# Angular template driven form with conditional validation in component file - value of #form.valid is up to date only after calling setTimeout()

Tags: angular, forms, validation

In Angular template driven form I want to validate input fields conditionally, based on which button was clicked. Then in the ts component file I check whether the form is valid i.e action can be executed or invalid i.e form data needs to be corrected. I use the form template reference variable to determine if form is valid or not `<form #heroForm="ngForm">`, then in the .ts file `@ViewChild('heroForm') form:Ngform;`
When a button is clicked I set the condition whether the field is required or not and then evaluate whether the form is valid or not.

However, when I set the variable `actionType = 'A'` so that the input is required and then right after evaluate `this.form.valid` it tells me the form is valid even though it is not ( required input is missing data)

```
this.actionType = 'A';//this make the input field required
if(this.form.valid){ // should be false but it is true (although later it changes to false)
 //code that should be executed when form is valid
}
```

After I debugged the app I noticed that setting a variable with new value then  running validation is done asynchronously, therefore `this.form.valid` is checked before previous operation is finished.

When I put the form checking code inside `setTimeout` it works but I am not sure this is the correct way to handle this case.

Is there any other way this should or can be solved?

I created a stackblitz sample to illustrate the problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g1nb9s

Watch the console output to see what is happening.

**Expected behaviour:**

- I click actionA button
- input field becomes required by setting `actionType = 'A'`
- value of `this.form.valid` in ts file should be `false` ( because input is required and is empty)

Currently when I click actionA button and read immediately `this.form.valid` in component file, then the value is `true`

Comment: Not sure why you're not able to do that. I just checked your StackBlitz sample, it's working as expected for me.

Comment: I added description of what expected behavior is, check it out. Watch the console output to notice that the form.valid is true even though data is missing in a required field.

Comment: No, it's not. The forms validity is set to `false` as soon as you click button a. Unless I'm extremely dumb and not noticing something obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I simplified the stackblitz sample not to be confusing. Open up the console and press actionA button.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `required` attribute with attribute binding syntax(`[required]="actionType === 'A'"`) which makes sense.

Since it's taking some time for Angular to detect these changes, you can explicitly tell Angular to do just that. This can be done by calling `detectChanges` on `ChangeDetectorRef` which you'll have to import from `@angular/core`.

Also, there's an issue with the type of `heroForm` that you've declared. `@ViewChild('heroForm') form: Ngform;` needs to be changed to `@ViewChild('heroForm') form: NgForm;` and `NgForm` needs to be `import`ed from `@angular/forms`:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

...
@ViewChild('heroForm') form: NgForm;
...
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
...
public onClickA() {
  this.actionType = 'A';
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  console.log("Value of actionType->" + this.actionType);
  console.log("Value of form.valid->" + this.form.valid);
}
```

Here's an [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-validations-cd?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Are you sure using `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` is the "official" way to do it and not just misusing the api?

Comment: Yeah I mean if Angular is not detecting changes and you want to make it do just that, I don't think we're misusing the API. Maybe it's just me. But I've seen it being used quite frequently in such scenarios and there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

Changes `actionType` will not immediately be reflected in `template`. These changes will be seen in the template only after the next tick. You can use `setTimeout` as follows:

```
  public onClickA(){
    this.actionType = 'A';
    setTimeout(()=>{this.buttonClicked()},0)
  }

  public onClickB(){
    this.actionType = 'B';
    setTimeout(()=>{this.buttonClicked()},0)
  }
```